# An easy way to inline frame a table?

Tags: tables, border

I have a table with a small width and I would like to frame it, so that the frame doesn't have 100% width of the page but rather is closely around the table.

```
\begin{tabular}{r@{ $\rightarrow$ }l}
    er & é\\
    ir & i\\
    dre & u\\
    oir & u\\
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: `\fbox{your super table}` perhaps. Or put in an another, outer table

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Not suggesting `tcolorbox`? `;-)`

Comment: @HarishKumar: Too much overhead :D

Comment: @Larivact: Depends on the way

Comment: @MartinSchröder Thanks :) This is my first day of using TeX and I am overwhelmed ... with joy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are some options:

- `\fbox{table environment}`
- `\begin{tabular}{|c|}...inner table environment \end{tabular}`
- `\frame{}` (Not used it ever so far and it's not shown here)
- `tcolorbox` (Harish Kumar ;-)` as one more sophisticated way

This list isn't complete of course.

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\fbox{%
  \begin{tabular}{r@{ $\rightarrow$ }l}
    er & é\\
    ir & i\\
    dre & u\\
    oir & u\\
  \end{tabular}
}


\begin{tabular}{|@{}c@{}|}
\hline
\begin{tabular}{r@{ $\rightarrow$ }l}
    er & é\\
    ir & i\\
    dre & u\\
    oir & u\\
\end{tabular}
\tabularnewline
\hline
\end{tabular}




\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced jigsaw,halign=center,boxrule=1pt,boxsep=0mm,left=2pt,right=2pt,sharp corners,width=3cm,colback=yellow,drop fuzzy shadow=blue]

\begin{tabular}{r@{ $\rightarrow$ }l}
    er & é\\
    ir & i\\
    dre & u\\
    oir & u\\
\end{tabular}
\end{tcolorbox}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: And there is `\frame{}`.

Comment: @MartinSchröder: Thanks, I added your suggestion